# SVN with APACHE on AIX - cannot load module mod_dav_svn.so

Tags: apache, svn, aix, mod-dav-svn

I'hve installed subversion and apache on my AIX server. Each one is running fine separately.
But when I try to launch apache with svn libraries included I got this error:

> httpd: Syntax error on line 523 of /opt/freeware/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 5 of /opt/freeware/etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-subversion.conf: Cannot load /opt/freeware/lib/httpd/modules/mod_dav_svn.so into server: rtld: 0712-001 Symbol ap_log_rerror was referenced\n      from module /opt/freeware/lib/httpd/modules/mod_dav_svn.so(), but a runtime definition\n      of the symbol was not found.\nrtld: 0712-001 Symbol dav_new_error_tag was referenced\n      from module /opt/freeware/lib/httpd/modules/mod_dav_svn.so(), but a runtime definition\n      of the symbol was not found.\nrtld: 0712-001 Symbol dav_push_error was referenced\n      from module /opt/freeware/lib/httpd/modules/mod_dav_svn.so(), but a runtime definition\n      of the symbol was not found.\nrtld: 0712-001 Symbol dav_new_error was referenced\n      from module /opt/freeware/lib/httpd/modules/mod_dav_svn.so(), but a runtime definition\n      of the symbol was not found.\nrtld: 0712-001 Symbol dav_xml_get_cdata was referenced\n      from module /opt/freeware/lib/httpd/modules/mod_dav_svn.so(), but a runtime definition\n      of the symbol was not found.\nrtld: 0712-001 Symbol dav_xmlns_add was referenced\n      from module /opt/freeware/lib/httpd/modules/mod_dav_svn.so(), but a runtime definition\n      of the symbol was not found.\nrtld: 0712-001 Symbol ap_log_perror was referenced\n      from module /opt/freeware/lib/httpd/modules/mod_dav_svn.so(), but a runtime definition\n      of the symbol was not found.\n\t0509-021 Additional errors occurred but are not reported.

I installed apache, subversion and mod_dav from perzl.com website:
subversion-1.7.6-1.aix5.1.ppc.rpm
httpd-2.4.3-1.aix5.1.ppc.rpm
mod_dav_svn-1.7.6-1.aix5.1.ppc.rpm

I'm running AIX 5.2:

> uname -a:
>   AIX mdsp16 2 5 000133DAD300

The error (line 523) is a link to the Loadmodule mod_dav_svn

Maybe the mod_dav_svn is corrupted but I dont know where to find a good version of it (I installed  the mod_dav_svn rpm many times).

I didn't find the same error on the Web and start giving it up ^^
Thx for any clue.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same experience as you. But I have the problem resolved by downloading a lower version of httpd -> `httpd-2.2.23-1.aix5.1.ppc.rpm` from [this site](http://www.oss4aix.org/download/RPMS/apache/).